# App crashes on Menu inflate. How to correct?

Tags: java, android

So I am trying to get a menu inflater to work using the following code from the activity where I want the menu.

when I click on the item to open my app closes down and I just get a message saying Unfortunately this app has stopped running.

could anyone help.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 MenuInflater blowUp = getMenuInflater();
 blowUp.inflate(R.menu.cool_menu, menu);

 return true;
}

@Override

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch(item.getItemId()){
case R.id.aboutUs:
    Intent i = new Intent(Menu.this, AboutUs.class);
    startActivity(i);
    break;
case R.id.prefs:

    break;
}
return false;
}
```

and this is the menu item clicked class:

```
public class AboutUs extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about);
}
```

logcat:

```
03-05 14:12:25.265: D/AbsListView(21911): Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-05 14:12:25.545: E/SpannableStringBuilder(21911): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-05 14:12:25.545: E/SpannableStringBuilder(21911): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-05 14:12:58.990: D/AbsListView(21911): Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-05 14:13:03.065: D/AndroidRuntime(21911): Shutting down VM
03-05 14:13:03.065: W/dalvikvm(21911): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ee92a0)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.learn.tam/com.example.learn.tam.AboutUs}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1420)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3446)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3407)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3617)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3585)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at com.example.learn.tam.Menu.onOptionsItemSelected(Menu.java:57)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2629)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1047)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:180)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1276)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3067)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3963)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
03-05 14:13:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21911):at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your LogCat output would be really helpful.

Comment: @swayam How Do I include that?

Comment: Go to the LogCat in Eclipse and just copy the errors from there.

Comment: My guess is you didn't include your AboutUs.class in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Without logcat i assume you've forgotten to add you AboutUs Activity to your manifest file.

Comment: I have added to logcat from When I press the About us menu item.  Also I do have the about us in the Manifiest, But I will recheck it.

Comment: Never mind,  I always miss the smallest things, There was a typo in my manifest, I used a capital by accident where I should not have.  It is weird I checked the manifest 3 times and did not notice this.  Sorry for what its not a pointless question.

Answer (score 2):

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class {com.example.learn.tam/com.example.learn.tam.AboutUs};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Declare your `AboutUs` activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`. If it is declared, make sure package name is correct in your declaration.